# phoenix deployment with EXRM cowboy server answered 500

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

my new project (I added "hello world" on the main page of the default mix new proj only)  works fine in dev

i configured it for prod according with phoenix site section and after that with this command

```
 MIX_ENV=prod iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

it works just fine

after that i created release by mix release - and all went fine during the process

after that i tried to start this release and it started, but did not work:

```
$> rel/hello/bin/hello console
Using /home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello/releases/0.0.1/hello.sh
Exec: /home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello/erts-7.3/bin/erlexec -boot /home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello/releases/0.0.1/hello
-mode embedded -config /home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello/running-config/sys.config
-boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello/erts-7.3/../lib 
-env ERL_LIBS /home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello/lib 
-pa /home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello/lib/hello-0.0.1/consolidated 
-args_file /home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello/running-config/vm.args 
-user Elixir.IEx.CLI -extra --no-halt +iex -- console
Root: /home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello
/home/bar/work/phoenix/hello/rel/hello


Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

17:09:39.614 [info] Running Hello.Endpoint with Cowboy using http on port 4001
Interactive Elixir (1.2.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(hello@localhost)1> 17:09:42.545 [error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.1183.0> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener Hello.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
** (exit) {:cowboy_handler, [class: :error, reason: :undef, mfa: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, :init, 2}, 
stacktrace: [{Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, :init, [{:http_req, #Port<0.3806>,
:ranch_tcp, :keepalive, #PID<0.1183.0>, "GET", :"HTTP/1.1", ................ 



    $> curl -v localhost:4001
    * Rebuilt URL to: localhost:4001/
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4001 (#0)
    > GET / HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost:4001
    > User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
    > Accept: */*
    > 
    < HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    < server: Cowboy
    < date: Fri, 22 Apr 2016 14:24:42 GMT
    < content-length: 0
    < 
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

wtf? howto? (i have read 'deployment' section on phoenixframework.org)

```
$> mix -v
Mix 1.2.4



$> elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.2.4
```

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

ok , i found out the reason of this my trouble

in main OTP already exist cowboy cowlib and ranch (in /usr/lib/erlang/lib dir)
after removing them - all goes fine!

phoenix rules!

Comment: If you had cowboy and ranch in your Erlang installation, you've probably used Erlang "Enterprise distribution", which is broken by design and causes many troubles like this. The best solution is to uninstall it and install "Standard" one.

Comment: tnx for your information. i am afraid that i put these libs myself, by hand, when played with cowboy and chickagoBoss

Comment: and if i install erlang distro as packet (arhc linux, pacman) does i have "Enterprise Distribution" in this case //// well i will ask google about "Enterprise distribution" and tnx u agn

Comment: If you played with it by hand, than I may be wrong. If you haven't installed Erlang using this site: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html don't mind my comment :)